# How do I display the result of this query using Joomla pagination?

Tags: php, joomla, pagination

What can I do to display the result of this query in the fronted using the Joomla pagination?

```
<?php
  $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM #__no_entreprise';
  $database->setQuery( $sql );
  $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
?
```

Answer (score 2):

See the Joomla docs - [Using JPagination in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component). In short, something like this:

```
$pageNav = new JPagination( $database->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );
echo $pageNav->getListFooter();
```